# How to send file contents from Windows to another machine on LAN

Tags: windows, shell, ftp, netcat

I am trying to stream (or periodically send) the contents of a file on a Windows machine to another machine on the same LAN.

I have tried using netcat, but get the "This app can't run on your PC" error, which could be because the computer I'm trying to send from is the Lenovo Ideacentre compute stick, which could be limited.

What are my alternatives? Such as writing the contents to a UDP packets, or using some other command. I am familiar with UNIX shell but just started using Windows command line, so I'm not very sure where to look.

Comment: Why not just share a filesystem with the other machine and it can help itself?

Comment: Ideally I want something low-level so that I can integrate it with programs I'm writing, but that might work.